# Jquery scrolltop with prev next not scrolling properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to setup jquery scrolltop with previous and next button, so that the user can scroll within a scrollable div.

I came across this post [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739786/scroll-to-next-and-previous-div-using-scrolltop-how-do-i-accomplish-this) and was trying to setup for my application, but it doesn't seems to scroll to the top of the next/previous div.

Could anyone point out where the problem is and perhaps a solution to it? Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

CSS:

```
.image_holder {
display: block;
height: 100%;
}

.section{
position: relative;
height: 80vh;
background: rgba(255, 226, 57, 0.0);
overflow-y: scroll;
margin: 0 auto;
border: #000000 solid thin;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page_scroller">
<ul >
<li class="list-unstyled col-lg-6 bg-primary"><a href="#" id="prev" class="arrow-up prev">Up</a></li>
<li class="list-unstyled col-lg-6 bg-primary"><a href="#" id="next" class="arrow-down next">Down</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="section" >

        <div id="highlight-1" class="current image_holder">A</div>
        <div id="highlight-2" class="image_holder ">B</div>
        <div id="highlight-3" class="image_holder ">C</div>
        <div id="highlight-4" class="image_holder ">D</div> 

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var scrollTo = function(element) {
    console.log(element);
    $('.section').animate({
        scrollTop: element.offset().top
    }, 500);
}

$('.next').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $current = $('.section > .image_holder.current');
    var $next = $current.next().first();
    if ($next.length!=0) {
        $current.removeClass('current')
        $next.addClass('current');
        scrollTo($next);
    }
});

$('.prev').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $current = $('.section > .image_holder.current');
    var $prev = $current.prev().first();
    if ($prev.length!=0) {
        $current.removeClass('current')
        $prev.addClass('current');
        scrollTo($prev);
    }
});
```

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gupointer/uoyx1jna/)

Comment: still looking for help...
I used Chrome inspection tool and notice that .current class was assigned correctly by jquery on clicks...but it is not scrolled to the intended section in the scrollable div...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually working as intended: it scrolls to the section, but it scrolls based on the top edge of the viewport, not based on the overflowed div.

Try replacing

```
$('.section').animate({
    scrollTop: element.offset().top
}, 500);
```

with

```
$('.section').animate({
    scrollTop: element.position().top
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! However problem persist...
seems that the code has problem when scrolling beyond the second div (with the button)